# How to reach 3rd Party Dom and interact with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app which is loading an external script which adds a header to my website.

This Header is then added to top of my page and its just pure javascript and html.

But it falls outside of my react app which is right below this header.

But I wish to add certain pieces of information to this 3rd party header from my react redux state.

How can I interact with this 3party div placed on my page from React ?

I.e. my current react render

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes(store, intl)}</Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and app html is something like

```
<body>
 <header>Something I want to change with redux data</header>
 <div id="app"><div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the external script is loaded. If it loads synchronously, before your React app, then you could do something like this in your React app:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
    // Do something with the header...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to add the header inside your React app? Something like this maybe.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <header>store.getstate().reducerName.headerdata</header>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes(store, intl)}</Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```